# How to apply opacity to div and all its child elements except one div which is a child element of the parent

Tags: css

I am trying to apply opacity to a parent div but not to one of its child div...I have made a demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/rLjuSo9336Qe67fXlkPe?p=preview where i am applying opacity to the maindiv which works perfectly but i dont want to apply the opacity to a div so making the opacity of the a particular div opacity to 1 but thats not working...How can i ignore the opacity of a parent div...

```
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div>div 1</div>
  <div>div 2</div>
  <div>
    <div id="div3">
     <input type="text" />
  </div>
  </div>
  <div>div 4</div>
</div>
```

In the above code i want to apply the opacity to maindiv and all its children but not to div which has id="div3"...Somebody please help me
Thank You..!

Comment: Sadly, ive tried the same thing before, and was unable to do so. You may have to look into relative or absolute positioning. Unless things have changed.

Comment: You can't do that that, once the parent has opacity, the child does, what you can do is use a pseudo element on the parent which can have opacity. With that you can achieve it

Comment: The question is; why (what for) do you need opacity on the parent?

Comment: This is not possible with CSS. You will need Javascript,

Comment: @Paulie_D My objective is to make a particular div to focus making all the other div elements to focusout... How can i make this using javascript?

Comment: It's Jquery an option or just pure JS ?

Comment: I would like to make it with pure js

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking into doing this with just CSS and nothing else, you are out of luck. Here is what [MDN has to say about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity).

> The value applies to the element as a whole, including its contents,
>   even though the value is not inherited by child elements. Thus, an
>   element and its contained children all have the same opacity relative
>   to the element's background, even if the element and its children have
>   different opacities relative to one another.

But, depending on what you **actually** want to achieve, it is still very likely that you can do it. Change your HTML in such a way that the element that you do not want opacity for is not a child of the element which has opacity.